# Update sql for 1 to many table (aka join table)

Tags: mysql, sql

consider an employee, and Usually on client side application, we add and remove roles and I'm looking for an efficient sql to handle add/remove.

### user

```
id, name
1, 'john'
2, 'joe'
```

### role

```
id, name
1, 'admin'
2, 'accounts'
3, 'finance'
4, 'marketing'
```

### user_role

```
user_id, role_id
1, 1
1, 2
2, 1
```

for instance, we have to assign `/user/1` role of '`account`' and '`finance` and remove `admin`

```
[2, 3]
```

My sql first deletes all the roles of this user, and then populates again from the array, and I see it like inefficient. Is there an SQL that updates the relation/join table, let's say `/user/1' was admin too but the client removed that role.

```
sql = 'DELETE FROM user_role WHERE id = ?; INSERT INTO user_role ?'
values = [request.params.id, request.body]
```

Is this correct or is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you think it's inefficient?

Comment: because first we delete all rows from the join table and insert again, usually on client side we only remove what's in there, wondering if database has built in something, or is this the only way what I've written?

Comment: why don't you simply delete the intersects you don't want followed by an insert of the ones you want in a separate query?

Comment: @Drew please help with an sql

Comment: in `user_role` delete using the `where` clause. The insert is pretty easy. Have a unique key composite on the two columns for no dupes